# Использование функции changePageTitle

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, методы, компоненты

Читал [Изменения в работе v-model](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/migration/v-model.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). В коде, приведенном в конце этой страницы, есть блок

```
// ChildComponent.vue

export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String // раньше было `value: String`
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  methods: {
    changePageTitle(title) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', title) // раньше было `this.$emit('input', title)`
    }
  }
}
```

Там зачем-то приведен метод changePageTitle. Где он используется (я внимательно прочитал статью, но не нашел нужного места)?

Comment: он используется в `template`